# Cannot make the string constant while assigning address from config file

Tags: c#, .net, string, constants

I have the address of endpoint of a webservice and have included that in the config file. When i try to read that and assign it to a variable i cannot have that variable as a constant. What do i do?

config file

`<appSettings>
<add key="KYCService" value="address">
<appSettings>`

c# code:

`string uri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KYCService"];`

i want uri to be a constant variable

Comment: Constants must be evaluated at compile time. Your configuration won't be read until runtime, so it cannot be constant. The best you could do is, if `uri` is a field, you can mark it as `readonly`.

Comment: Why do you want it to be a constant at all? You could make it `static readonly`

Comment: ... or make a property that only has a getter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constant using the [`const`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) keyword needs to be known at compile time.

> A constant expression is an expression that can be fully evaluated at compile time.

The settings from the config file are only loaded in run time. So it can never be a `const`.

You can use `static readonly` in your case.